# Jenkins for a maven project - generating test reports

Tags: android, maven, build, continuous-integration, jenkins

I am using Jenkins 1.450 for CI, my source code is in a git repo, and I am using maven as build environment.

**My problem:** I cannot get Jenkins to generate test results.

**Details:** 

1. If I create a 'freestyle' job in Jenkins, it executes the build successfully. But, if I select the 'Publish JUnit test result report' option, Jenkins cannot find the test report files. I can see them in target/surefire-reports/ if I do 'mvn install' myself, but Jenkins somehow doesn't build in the workplace... after a Jenkins build, I don't see this target directory created.

2. If I create 'Maven 2/3' job, and give it path to my Maven installation, Jenkins simply does not find it - it says: `<path>/Maven_3.0.4 doesn't have a 'lib' subdirectory - thus cannot be a valid maven installation!`

The error doesn't change even after giving read-write-execute permissions to all users for this directory.

What is it that I am doing wrong here? Do I need to have the `<reporting>` tag in my pom files? Where can I find documentation/troubleshooting info for all this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven 2/3 project satisfies our test-reports requirements. Once I saw that, I went ahead and figured out the problems in building the same.

I followed these steps to install Maven: http://lukieb.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/installing-maven-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server/, and then made sure that path to maven install was set properly in Jenkins.

As we are building Android applications, the next problem was ANDROID_HOME variable - Jenkins could not find Android SDK location without it. Doing a `export` didn't help; it never 'stuck'. Moreover, the `PATH` seen by Jenkins and by `echo $PATH` did not match. The answer was modifying `/etc/profile`, and adding `export ANDROID_HOME` and then `export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH` there. (I got this from another Stackoverflow question.)

After all this, now my CI setup is working.

[I am accepting this answer, please let me know if you need further info...]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me on Ubuntu 14.04, `mvn` was installed in `/usr/share/maven/bin`, but what Jenkins is really asking for is where the Maven `bin` folder can be found which is: `/usr/share/maven`.